# order list of data depending on newest date or older date in ioni2 angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have json format data :

```
[{date: 2017-10-18T03:00:00+03:00 , name : 'A'},
{date: 2017-11-18T03:00:00+03:00 , name : 'B'}]
```

so how to display these data from the newest date to the oldest date.
the result will be :

```
B
A
```

because B is newest

Comment: sort it based on your date, and pick the latest one.

Comment: yes i know it is based on the date but how to sort it. how to display the newest date first. the data above is an example but I have a 10 objects and may more

Comment: import * as _ from 'lodash';  let sortedData =  _.orderBy(yourData, ['date'], ['desc']);

Comment: i need a custom pipe to do it

Comment: So you just need pipe, not other method?

Comment: @SamuelShyu it's a good solution, i tried it and it works fine. but is there any other solution like custom pipe or somethinhg

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom pipe like below.  Then in your html add the pipe as | arraySort:['date', 'DESC']

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
    name: 'arraySort'
})
export class ArraySortPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: Array<{}>, args: string[]): Array<string> | Array<{}> {

        array = array || [];

        if (typeof args === 'undefined' || args.length !== 2) {
            return array;
        }

        const [key, direction] = args;

        if (direction !== 'ASC' && direction !== 'DESC') {
            return array;
        }

        return _.orderBy(array, (item:any) => item[key], direction.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```